# SVN bad files *.r52 *.v47

Tags: svn, labview

I have a problem with my labview project and SVN. My LV project is made of 2 cRIO (cRIO1 and cRIO2) which share the same core code into a "common" in svn. What's happen? If I change something in cRIO1 and commit in SVN, I receive a conflict message seems due to presence of file with the same extension(*.r52,*.r47).
My SVN project structure is (under trunk):
[image]

and under cRIO I had the classic LV project structure
[image]

Someone has an experience about LV, common code and SVN ?

Comment: Step one: change your version control system to git, if possible. This problem probably wouldn't even show up in git. I recommend GitKraken for a nice GUI interface to git.

Comment: Agree with @AdrianKeister. The issue which you have here - results of merge conflicts, so your files are saved automatically with different revisions. SourceTree from Atlassian is also nice git UI.

Comment: Thanks Adrian and kosist

Comment: LabView uses binary files; i've used git with LabView, but it's pretty unpleasant.

Answer (score 1):

### What happened?

A while ago, you updated your working copy to revision 47.
You as well as someone else modified this file, but the other guy was faster in committing this file to SVN.

Now, you try an update to revision 52. SVN doesn't know how to handle those changes, and marks the file as conflicted. It creates a `.r52` file, which is the file from SVN and a `.r47` file, which is the file you got from SVN a while ago.

If the file is a binary file, the original file is just your file before the update.
If the file is a text file, SVN marks your changes as yours, adds the changes from revision 52, and marks them as theirs. That is, SVN modifies your file!
The content of the file before your attempt to update is found in a `.mine` file.

As you see, you can edit the conflicts by hand, but you can also do this with SVN using the *resolve* function. In tortoiseSVN, right-click a directory, and choose SVN -> resolve conflicts. It will show all conflicts, and you can select if you want to keep your modifications (mine) or those from the repository (theirs).
Usually, SVN lists the conflicted files during an update, and you can select what to do. It seems you did not do so...

### LabVIEW and version control

Version control of LV is tricky. Most files are binary files, and it is not easily possible to merge two versions of a file with different modifications to a new one containing both.
The biggest problem is that LV is notorious in modifying files, often for no obvious reason. This leaves you with lots of files you did not edit, but which are modified by LV and want to be committed to SVN. Finally, you'll have many many conflicts all the time, and don't now which versions are the correct ones...

You can't get rid of this problem completely, but you can reduce it by *separating compiled code from VIs*. By default, VIs contain the block diagramm (source code) as well as the compiled binary. That is, even if there is no change to the block diagramm / front panel, but it has to be re-compiled, the file is modified. By separating the compiled code, it is put into a cache outside the project directory. This also reduces the file size by about 30%.

There is a global setting in LV to separate the compiled code for new VIs, and each VI has a check box in its properties. Unfortunately, there is no automatic ways to do this for an entire project in one go.

Comment: Separating compiled code from source is good advice. (I don't know why this isn't the default; it should be required.) For existing code it is easy to use the VI Server to walk the project, open each VI or CTL, set ContainsCompiledCode=False, and save it. This will create more one awful commit, but will avoid future conflicts.